# Finite injective resolution of a constant sheaf

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, sheaf-theory, injective-module

Is it known if the injective resolution of the constant sheaf $\mathbb C_X$ on a smooth manifold $X$ is of finite length? I am asking this because the fine resolution of $\mathbb C_X$ in terms of the De Rham complex is finite.